# Javascript Datepicker - Selecting date then time

Tags: javascript, html, date, time, datepicker

**Please be aware that I am a total noob at JS, sorry if I don't understand basic coding language. Solutions are very welcome. Thanks!**

I have created my own form and have two input fields which consist of 'date of incident' and 'time of incident'. The user will need to select a date either the current date or previous dates only. Then the user will select a time and if the user selected the current date it can only be before the current time. Otherwise anytime is ok.

I have already developed the datepicker for 'date of incident' but I need all the dates after the current date to be grayed out, im not sure if I will need to use 'minDate' or 'maxDate' for this and if I will need to implement it to a existing function or create a new one.

For the 'time of incident' I am using 'type="time".

I have got a little bit of an idea for the date of incident:

currentDate = today

futureDates = greyed out

but I am starting out with JavaScript and don't really know how to implement it properly into the code.

HTML:

```
<input id="datepick" placeholder="Enter the date of incident" type="text"/>

<input id="timepick" placeholder="Enter the time of incident" type="time"/>
```

Javascript for Datepicker:

```
var datepickr = (function() {
    var datepickrs = [],
    currentDate = new Date(),
    date = {
        current: {
            year: function() {
                return currentDate.getFullYear();
            },
            month: {
                integer: function() {
                    return currentDate.getMonth();
                },
                string: function(full, months) {
                    var date = currentDate.getMonth();
                    return monthToStr(date, full, months);
                    minDate: currentDate;
                }
            },
            day: function() {
                return currentDate.getDate();           
            }
        },
        month: {
            string: function(full, currentMonthView, months) {
                var date = currentMonthView;
                return monthToStr(date, full, months);
            },
            numDays: function(currentMonthView, currentYearView) {
                /* checks to see if february is a leap year otherwise return the respective # of days */
                return (currentMonthView == 1 && !(currentYearView & 3) && (currentYearView % 1e2 || !(currentYearView % 4e2))) ? 29 : daysInMonth[currentMonthView];
            }
        }
    },
    daysInMonth = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31],
    buildCache = [],
    handlers = {
        calendarClick: function(e) {
            if(e.target.className) {
                switch(e.target.className) {
                    case 'prev-month':
                    case 'prevMonth':
                        this.currentMonthView--;
                        if(this.currentMonthView < 0) {
                            this.currentYearView--;
                            this.currentMonthView = 11;
                        }
                        rebuildCalendar.call(this);
                    break;
                    case 'next-month':
                    case 'nextMonth':
                        this.currentMonthView++;
                        if(this.currentMonthView > 11) {
                            this.currentYearView++;
                            this.currentMonthView = 0;
                        }
                        rebuildCalendar.call(this);
                    break;
                    case 'day':
                        this.element.value = formatDate(new Date(this.currentYearView, this.currentMonthView, e.target.innerHTML).getTime(), this.config);
                        this.close();
                    break;
                }
            }
        },
        documentClick: function(e) {
            if(e.target != this.element && e.target != this.calendar) {
                var parentNode = e.target.parentNode;
                if(parentNode != this.calender) {
                    while(parentNode != this.calendar) {
                        parentNode = parentNode.parentNode;
                        if(parentNode == null) {
                            this.close();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    function formatDate(milliseconds, config) {
        var formattedDate = '',
        dateObj = new Date(milliseconds),
        format = {
            d: function() {
                var day = format.j();
                return (day < 10) ? '0' + day : day;
            },
            D: function() {
                return config.weekdays[format.w()].substring(0, 3);
            },
            j: function() {
                return dateObj.getDate();
            },
            l: function() {
                return config.weekdays[format.w()];
            },
            S: function() {
                return config.suffix[format.j()] || config.defaultSuffix;
            },
            w: function() {
                return dateObj.getDay();
            },
            F: function() {
                return monthToStr(format.n(), true, config.months);
            },
            m: function() {
                var month = format.n() + 1;
                return (month < 10) ? '0' + month : month;
            },
            M: function() {
                return monthToStr(format.n(), false, config.months);
            },
            n: function() {
                return dateObj.getMonth();
            },
            Y: function() {
                return dateObj.getFullYear();
            },
            y: function() {
                return format.Y().toString().substring(2, 4);
            }
        },
        formatPieces = config.dateFormat.split('');

        foreach(formatPieces, function(formatPiece, index) {
            if(format[formatPiece] && formatPieces[index - 1] != '\\') {
                formattedDate += format[formatPiece]();
            } else {
                if(formatPiece != '\\') {
                    formattedDate += formatPiece;
                }
            }
        });

        return formattedDate;
    }

    function foreach(items, callback) {
        var i = 0, x = items.length;
        for(i; i < x; i++) {
            if(callback(items[i], i) === false) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    function addEvent(element, eventType, callback) {
        if(element.addEventListener) {
            element.addEventListener(eventType, callback, false);
        } else if(element.attachEvent) {
            var fixedCallback = function(e) {
                e = e || window.event;
                e.preventDefault = (function(e) {
                    return function() { e.returnValue = false; }
                })(e);
                e.stopPropagation = (function(e) {
                    return function() { e.cancelBubble = true; }
                })(e);
                e.target = e.srcElement;
                callback.call(element, e);
            };
            element.attachEvent('on' + eventType, fixedCallback);
        }
    }

    function removeEvent(element, eventType, callback) {
        if(element.removeEventListener) {
            element.removeEventListener(eventType, callback, false);
        } else if(element.detachEvent) {
            element.detachEvent('on' + eventType, callback);
        }
    }

    function buildNode(nodeName, attributes, content) {
        var element;

        if(!(nodeName in buildCache)) {
            buildCache[nodeName] = document.createElement(nodeName);
        }

        element = buildCache[nodeName].cloneNode(false);

        if(attributes != null) {
            for(var attribute in attributes) {
                element[attribute] = attributes[attribute];
            }
        }

        if(content != null) {
            if(typeof(content) == 'object') {
                element.appendChild(content);
            } else {
                element.innerHTML = content;
            }
        }

        return element;
    }

    function monthToStr(date, full, months) {
        return ((full == true) ? months[date] : ((months[date].length > 3) ? months[date].substring(0, 3) : months[date]));
    }

    function isToday(day, currentMonthView, currentYearView) {
        return day == date.current.day() && currentMonthView == date.current.month.integer() && currentYearView == date.current.year();
    }

    function buildWeekdays(weekdays) {
        var weekdayHtml = document.createDocumentFragment();
        foreach(weekdays, function(weekday) {
            weekdayHtml.appendChild(buildNode('th', {}, weekday.substring(0, 2)));
        });
        return weekdayHtml;
    }

    function rebuildCalendar() {
        while(this.calendarBody.hasChildNodes()){
            this.calendarBody.removeChild(this.calendarBody.lastChild);
        }

        var firstOfMonth = new Date(this.currentYearView, this.currentMonthView, 1).getDay(),
        numDays = date.month.numDays(this.currentMonthView, this.currentYearView);

        this.currentMonth.innerHTML = date.month.string(this.config.fullCurrentMonth, this.currentMonthView, this.config.months) + ' ' + this.currentYearView;
        this.calendarBody.appendChild(buildDays(firstOfMonth, numDays, this.currentMonthView, this.currentYearView));
    }

    function buildCurrentMonth(config, currentMonthView, currentYearView, months) {
        return buildNode('span', { className: 'current-month' }, date.month.string(config.fullCurrentMonth, currentMonthView, months) + ' ' + currentYearView);
    }

    function buildMonths(config, currentMonthView, currentYearView) {
        var months = buildNode('div', { className: 'months' }),
        prevMonth = buildNode('span', { className: 'prev-month' }, buildNode('span', { className: 'prevMonth' }, '&lt;')),
        nextMonth = buildNode('span', { className: 'next-month' }, buildNode('span', { className: 'nextMonth' }, '&gt;'));

        months.appendChild(prevMonth);
        months.appendChild(nextMonth);

        return months;
    }

    function buildDays(firstOfMonth, numDays, currentMonthView, currentYearView) {
        var calendarBody = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        row = buildNode('tr'),
        dayCount = 0, i;

        /* print out previous month's "days" */
        for(i = 1; i <= firstOfMonth; i++) {
            row.appendChild(buildNode('td', null, '&nbsp;'));
            dayCount++;
        }

        for(i = 1; i <= numDays; i++) {
            /* if we have reached the end of a week, wrap to the next line */
            if(dayCount == 7) {
                calendarBody.appendChild(row);
                row = buildNode('tr');
                dayCount = 0;
            }

            var todayClassName = isToday(i, currentMonthView, currentYearView) ? { className: 'today' } : null;
            row.appendChild(buildNode('td', todayClassName, buildNode('span', { className: 'day' }, i)));

            dayCount++;
        }

        /* if we haven't finished at the end of the week, start writing out the "days" for the next month */
        for(i = 1; i <= (7 - dayCount); i++) {
            row.appendChild(buildNode('td', null, '&nbsp;'));
        }

        calendarBody.appendChild(row);

        return calendarBody;
    }

    function buildCalendar() {
        var firstOfMonth = new Date(this.currentYearView, this.currentMonthView, 1).getDay(),
        numDays = date.month.numDays(this.currentMonthView, this.currentYearView),
        self = this;

        var inputLeft = inputTop = 0,
        obj = this.element;

        if(obj.offsetParent) {
            do {
                inputLeft += obj.offsetLeft;
                inputTop += obj.offsetTop;
            } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
        }

        var calendarContainer = buildNode('div', { className: 'calendar' });
        calendarContainer.style.cssText = 'display: none; position: absolute; top: ' + (inputTop + this.element.offsetHeight) + 'px; left: ' + inputLeft + 'px; z-index: 100;';

        this.currentMonth = buildCurrentMonth(this.config, this.currentMonthView, this.currentYearView, this.config.months)
        var months = buildMonths(this.config, this.currentMonthView, this.currentYearView);
        months.appendChild(this.currentMonth);

        var calendar = buildNode('table', null, buildNode('thead', null, buildNode('tr', { className: 'weekdays' }, buildWeekdays(this.config.weekdays))));
        this.calendarBody = buildNode('tbody');
        this.calendarBody.appendChild(buildDays(firstOfMonth, numDays, this.currentMonthView, this.currentYearView));
        calendar.appendChild(this.calendarBody);

        calendarContainer.appendChild(months);
        calendarContainer.appendChild(calendar);

        document.body.appendChild(calendarContainer);

        addEvent(calendarContainer, 'click', function(e) { handlers.calendarClick.call(self, e); });

        return calendarContainer;
    }

    return function(elementId, userConfig) {
        var self = this;

        this.element = document.getElementById(elementId);
        this.config = {
            fullCurrentMonth: true,
            dateFormat: 'F jS, Y',
            weekdays: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
            months: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
            suffix: { 1: 'st', 2: 'nd', 3: 'rd', 21: 'st', 22: 'nd', 23: 'rd', 31: 'st' },
            defaultSuffix: 'th'
        };
        this.currentYearView = date.current.year();
        this.currentMonthView = date.current.month.integer();

        if(userConfig) {
            for(var key in userConfig) {
                if(this.config.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    this.config[key] = userConfig[key];
                }
            }
        }

        this.documentClick = function(e) { handlers.documentClick.call(self, e); }

        this.open = function(e) {
            addEvent(document, 'click', self.documentClick);

            foreach(datepickrs, function(datepickr) {
                if(datepickr != self) {
                    datepickr.close();
                }
            });

            self.calendar.style.display = 'block';
        }

        this.close = function() {
            removeEvent(document, 'click', self.documentClick);
            self.calendar.style.display = 'none';
        }

        this.calendar = buildCalendar.call(this);

        datepickrs.push(this);

        if(this.element.nodeName == 'INPUT') {
            addEvent(this.element, 'focus', this.open);
        } else {
            addEvent(this.element, 'click', this.open);
        }
    }
})();
```

Sorry I don't have any code for my 'Time of Incident' field but I have a small psuedocode that I would like to turn into JavaScript and implement it into my code:

```
currentDate = new Date()

currentTime = new Date(time)

function timeSelect{

if{ 

datepicker = currentDate

{ 
time = currentTime (Can't select time past now, greyed out)

else
{
any time can be selected
}
```

Thank you for your time, it really helps me out.

-MrMaestro